# How to convert a bigint to float

Tags: sql-server

I know that a bigint should implicitly convert to a float but it does not seem to.

Table column to be updated:

```
[GBUsed] [float] NOT NULL,
```

Example of data in that column:

430.5

Logic: I'm summing 2 bigint columns together and dividing by 1024. An example of 1 of the row - I get: 1545

I the update the GBUsed column which is defined as float but it does not convert. I still get the 1545.

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RecalculateBandwidthUsage]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @RowCount int,
            @Rc int,
            @Message varchar(max),
            @CurrentDateTime datetime

    CREATE TABLE #Temp 
    (
        SwitchID int,
        PortIndex int,
        SwitchIP varchar(50),
        GBUsed bigint 
    )

    SET @CurrentDateTime = GETDATE()

    -- FOR TESTING: 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        INSERT #Temp (SwitchID, PortIndex, SwitchIP, GBUsed)
            SELECT 
                c.SwitchID, c.PortIndex,
                s.SwitchIP, 
                SUM ((c.BandwidthIn + c.BandwidthOut) / 1024) AS GBUsed     -- converting to gigabytes
            FROM 
                dbo.BandwidthLogCalculatedTest6 c
            INNER JOIN 
                Switch s ON (c.SwitchID = s.SwitchID)
            WHERE 
                (c.StartDate < DATEADD(HOUR, -1, @CurrentDateTime)  
                AND c.EntryType = 'Second')
            GROUP BY 
                c.SwitchID, c.PortIndex, s.SwitchIP
            ORDER BY 
                c.PortIndex

    SELECT 
        @Rc = @@ERROR,
        @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT       

    IF @Rc <> 0
    BEGIN 
       SELECT @Message = 'Critical Error - procedure RecalculateBandwidthUsage - on select. Return code: ' + Cast(@Rc as varchar)
       RAISERROR (@Message, 16, 1)
    END

    -- FOR TESTING:
    SELECT 'Temp table '

    SELECT * 
    FROM #temp
    ORDER BY PortIndex

    IF @RowCount > 0
    BEGIN
        -- FOR TESTING:
        SELECT 'Before update '

        SELECT b.SwitchIP, b.SwitchPort, b.GBUsed
        FROM dbo.Bandwidth b
        INNER JOIN #temp t ON (b.SwitchIP = t.SwitchIP AND b.SwitchPort = t.PortIndex )
        ORDER BY b.SwitchPort

        -- Update.
        UPDATE dbo.Bandwidth
        SET GBUsed = CONVERT(float, t.Gbused)
        FROM #Temp t
        WHERE (Bandwidth.SwitchIP = t.SwitchIP AND Bandwidth.SwitchPort = t.PortIndex)

        SELECT @Rc = @@ERROR 

        IF @Rc <> 0
        BEGIN 
            SELECT @Message = 'Critical Error - procedure RecalculateBandwidthUsage - on Bandwidth update. Return code: ' + Cast(@Rc as varchar)
            RAISERROR (@Message, 16, 1)
        END

        -- FOR TESTING:
        SELECT 'After update '

        SELECT b.SwitchIP, b.SwitchPort, b.GBUsed
        FROM dbo.Bandwidth b
        INNER JOIN #temp t ON (b.SwitchIP = t.SwitchIP AND b.SwitchPort = t.PortIndex)
        ORDER BY b.SwitchPort
    END

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing an **integer** division - so therefore, your result will also be an integer (or `BIGINT`).

You need to use this code in order to get fractional values:

```
SUM ((c.BandwidthIn + c.BandwidthOut) / 1024.0) AS GBUsed
```

Dividing by `1024.0` (instead of just `1024`) will make sure to use fractional values

Comment: marc_s...I had to change my temp table colum to: GBUsed float and then my insert to: CONVERT(decimal(18,2), SUM(c.BandwidthIn + c.BandwidthOut) / 1024.0 )  AS GBUsed in order to get the float value i am expecting.